# how it's possible to overload one image over another

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to put one image over another .i want to be the flame on top of the candle.but which is working as just opposite as what i'm thinking ,i'm adding my code below

```css
.candle-container{
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    
}
.candle-flame{
    margin-left: 10%;
    
}
.candl{
    margin-left: 91%;
}
    .img-candle{
        height: 399px;
        width: 157px;
        z-index: 9;
        overflow: none;
    }
.img-flame{
    margin-left: 20%;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 103.5%;
    margin-bottom: -4%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 46%;
    
}
.fire-box{
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: medium;
    width: 32%;
    height: 14%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 27%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 22%;
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="candle-container">
            <div class="candle-flame">
                <img src="img/flame.png" class="img-flame">
            </div>
            <div class="candl">
                <img src="img/candle.png" class="img-candle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fire-box">
            <button type="button">Fire</button>
            <button type="button">Stop</button>
        </div>
```

i'm tried to put z-index for both images ,but which is not working again,i pinned the screen shot of what i get on below.
[image: this is what i get]

i want to be the flame on top of the candle,but it appears as just opposite.i pinned the images i'm used on below
[image: candle]
[image: flame]

how can i fix this?.any help will get appreciated..!!!!

Comment: please check my answer, it is responsive for all device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added styling to `img-flame` class set `position: absolute` and did some `left` `top` styling.

```css
.candle-container{
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    
}
.candle-flame{
    margin-left: 10%;
    
}
.candl{
    margin-left: 91%;
}
    .img-candle{
        height: 399px;
        width: 157px;
        z-index: 9;
        overflow: none;
    }
.img-flame{
    position: absolute;
    top: 23%;
    width: 3%;
    height: 14%;
    margin-left: 51%;
}
.fire-box{
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: medium;
    width: 32%;
    height: 14%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 27%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 22%;
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="candle-container">
            <div class="candle-flame">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fab.png" class="img-flame">
            </div>
            <div class="candl">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDdGA.png" class="img-candle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fire-box">
            <button type="button">Fire</button>
            <button type="button">Stop</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: that isn't really responsive, if you resize the page, the flame will be floating somewhere else in the screen, this is because the flame takes the properties of it's parent, which is `candle-container` and not `candl`

Comment: Yes you have to write the styling for it. I just put the code so you can see how to display one image over another.

Comment: true that, didn't understand that that was what you were going for

Answer (score 0):

try putting the candle as the background of a div, then put the flame in that div and set it's position to `absolute`, then position it using `top, left, right, bottom` onto the candle

Answer (score 0):

Try below css and it will be responsive for any device.

```css
.candle-container {
  height: 40%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
.candle-flame {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-flame {
  height: auto;
  margin: -25px auto;
  width: auto;
}
.candl {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-candle {
  height: 399px;
  width: 157px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.fire-box {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: medium;
  height: 14%;
  margin-left: 27%;
  margin-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 22%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="candle-container">
            <div class="candle-flame">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fab.png" class="img-flame">
            </div>
            <div class="candl">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDdGA.png" class="img-candle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fire-box">
            <button type="button">Fire</button>
            <button type="button">Stop</button>
        </div>
```